# Removing the quotation marks from MYSQL query in LUA Code

Tags: mysql, lua, quotations

I am currently in the process of coding a script, using LUA. The script itself is designed to check if certain jobs are whitelisted (its a FiveM script). When switching jobs, it will save your current rank into the database, then switch over to the new job, so if you ever want to go back to the old one you will have your rank restored.

```
                MySQL.Sync.execute('UPDATE users SET `@jobselect` = @currentrank WHERE identifier    
                = @identifier3', {
                ['@jobselect'] = currentjob2,
                ['@currentrank'] = xPlayer.job.grade,
                ['@identifier3'] = xPlayer.getIdentifier()
                })
```

Through the console, I ran each of those variables, currentjob2, xPlayer.job.grade, etc. They all return what I expected them to. Then when I try to execute that MySQL query, I get the following error:

```
Unknown Column ''ems_rank'' in 'field list'
```

**ems_rank** is the result of the variable currentjob2 (just letting you know)

So, I can tell the issue is that the column's name is just *ems_rank* whereas the code is reading the quotation marks and assuming the column is called *'ems_rank'* when it isnt. So if anybody could help me find a way to remove the quotations, that would be much appreciated.

Bare in mind I am coding all this in LUA.

Comment: `print(currentjob2)` and show the result.

Comment: It comes back with:

ems_rank

exactly like that

Comment: `'ems_rank'` or `ems_rank`?

Comment: just ems_rank without the quotations

Comment: Why is `@jobselect` in quotation marks in your SQL?

Comment: [Lua](http://lua.org/about.html#name)*

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I removed those and now I get a different error saying I have an error in my SQL Syntax, but it doesn't tell me what is wrong

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it! It was an issue with the variable, I just executed individually, instead of using a variable.